# (cloud firestore) vc1 has snapshot listener on doc, passes doc data to vc2. vc2 writes data to doc, how to update data on vc2?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My first view controller has a snapshotlistener on a document then passes this doc data onto my second view controller- by let vc = vc2(data:data), the user than navigates to my second vcontroller and has the option to write data to the document.

When the user writes to the document my snapshot listener fires, and the data in vc1 is updated, but obviously the data in vc2 wont be updated.

I could add a function in vc2 to read data from firebase as soon as i call the function to write, but I'm curious if there is a better method of passing the data from vc1 to vc2 so that the data in vc2 is updated when the snapshot listener in vc1 fires?

Comment: You could have one class that represents the "state" of your app -- it would have the listener and current firestorm data. That class would get passed by reference (not by value) through the view controllers. Then any vc with access to that class would see the update(s).

Comment: with how you've structured it, you can have vc2 be an observer of vc1. personally, i would create a view model that is what listens to firebase and have both vc1 & vc2 listen to changes in the view model.

Answer (score 2):

This decision depends on (1) how many view controllers deep this will go and (2) how you handle these types of situations elsewhere in your app.

To the first point, if there are no other view controllers that need to know this data beyond the second one, then just have the first view controller call a method on the second view controller when data updates. But if there are more view controllers down this navigation stack that need to know about this data update, then I'd consider something else--perhaps a shared resource like a data manager or a view model that all view controllers observe or posting a local notification.

To the second point, just be consistent. However you normally handle these realtime-data situations, try to keep doing that. For instance, if you normally use protocols, use them here.

But for pure simplicity in a scenario where the second view controller is the only other object interested in the data updates in the first view controller, just have the first notify the second:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    private var vc2: VC2? // Make it an instance property that the navigation controller pushes to.
    
    Firestore.firestore().document(docPath).addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
        vc2?.dataDidUpdate() // If the second view controller was never instantiated, the optional chaining of vc2 will fail silently.
    })
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    func dataDidUpdate() {
        // update UI
    }
}
```